# export data as csv,pdf via the browser only by javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a web page which shows some data.
I would like to give the user the ability to export that data they see as CSV files or PDF files or other formats.

is it technically possible to do so purely by javascript ?

Thanks

Comment: Try DataTable [Table Tools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/), its flash/jquery cambo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: @FAngel thanks I did not realize somebody else had asked something similar thanks

Comment: The question is a duplicate of this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To a certain extent this can be resolved:

here is a link which triggers a 'save as' download:

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,Zm9vIGJhcg==">text file</a>
```

so the trick is to use data:application/octet-stream;

note however that it is not possible to specify the extension of the filename/resource you would save (e.g. report.csv)